# Strange 2sxc content (CKEditor) in DNN

Tags: ckeditor, dotnetnuke

We use **DNN with 2sxc and CKEditor**. By now if I opened the 2sxc it looked like this:

[image: screenshot before]

Today I suddenly have this view instead:

[image: screenshot after]

Accidentally this new view is what my colleagues had wanted to have too, but by now were not able to set up.

Does anybody know, which settings exactly lead to this new view?

**Additional info:**

Looks like the CKEditor in my user profile is not being loaded anymore:

[image: screenshot before]

[image: screenshot before]

Comment: Try set the CKEditor View mode from "Text" to "Html", see if it fix your issue.

Comment: Klick onto the HTML radio button didn't help, unfortunately. 
I added now additional info, it looks like the CKEditor in my user profile is not being loaded anymore.